# Choosing an appropriate gate driver for IRLZ44N high side for a buck converter

Tags: mosfet, integrated-circuit, buck, gate-driving, high-side

*For the TL;DR folks:*

- Need high side NMOS gate driver IC, similar to [Julian Ilett's DCOI driver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uff1nzFo140) but cheaper, higher switching speed and less complex;
- THT highly preferred, because 1,27mm perfboard is hard to get where I live, and ordering PCBs would quickly get expensive because of failed attempts, and it is already hard to order them here in Poland;
- Supply voltage of 12V and 5V present to power Arduino and other low voltage components, would be nice if I could power the driver with it as well;
- Don't want to use a dedicated buck converter IC because I want a "universal" NMOS driver for other applications like motor speed control or other, would prefer to buy in bulk and have on hand so I can just plop it down between the NMOS and whatever logic output;

Hello there! Excuse me if I ask a question that has been asked a milion times already, but I didn't seem to be able to find an answer when searching this site.

I am designing my own buck converter to be used as a variable voltage/current switch mode power supply. Thinking about a range of 0-50V and around 0-10A (might settle on 0-40V, because 50V is uncomfortably close to Vdss of the chosen MOSFET, which will be IRLZ44N because it's abundant here in Poland and I have a pack of a hundred of them at my disposal, and its current capabilities are good 'n proper for what I need)

I want it to be high-side, because low-side switching can get problematic in some situations, and PMOS has its drawbacks. But currently I went into a pickle with choosing the correct MOSFET gate driver IC. I have no idea which IC should I use, and what parameters should I consider while choosing one. The only thing I know is, that it won't be a very high frequency circuit (might settle on somewhere in the 22kHz-25kHz so it's not audible frequency), because I'm planning on building it on a piece of perfboard, so that might get messy pretty fast if I use HF switching, and the perfboard also means, that I'd really ***prefer a THT IC*** (1.27mm/0.05" pitch perfs are **really** hard to find out here), and all ICs I find are SMT, and I'd have to get adapter PCBs from i.e. SO-8 to DIP-8. I'd prefer not to have to deal with it, honestly. If there is no IC that fits what I look for, I'll be forced to order a PCB from a fab like JLCPCB or other similiar service, and as an inexperienced PCB designer, I think I'll spend way too much money and time on redesigning the PCB multiple times and reordering it, and the availability of such services in Poland is a bit iffy most of the time.

So far the only thing that I came across that actually hit the mark almost perfectly was [Julian Ilett's DCOI driver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uff1nzFo140), and if I had something exactly like that one, only in a single IC (of course the bootstrap cap would be separate), I'd be really glad, as this one costs a bit much to build and it has quite a footprint with two optoisolators and two diodes, and the charge/discharge rates aren't that good, so high power loss on the NMOS is to be expected.

Also, another question... I've heard that its considered to be a bad thing to use an AVR microcontroller as the logic side of a buck converter, because the program could get stuck and leave the NMOS in its HIGH state... What should I use then, except for dedicated buck converter ICs? I want this circuit to be an universal "oh, I need to use a MOSFET driven with PWM for this" IC, that I just plop down between the MOSFET, and whatever logic output, be it an Arduino, a 555 timer, or else.

EDIT: I've found a THT IC that seems to be readily available here in Poland ([MC33152PG](https://www.tme.eu/Document/edb150860a038bdde677ab295335a4e1/MC33152PG.PDF)), but it doesn't seem to support bootstrapping, so I'd have to power it from an isolated power supply in order to be able to drive the high-side NMOS with it... So, for example, if I have a 12V power supply that is completely separate from the main power circuit, will this work? Also, do I need to connect the ground of the power circuit with the ground of the 12V circuit?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9QO1B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: For this frequency you may have a look at these drivers: IR2184(4), IRS2111. They provide internal dead time and have a single input and DIP case.